# NSSortDescriptor and nil values

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm using an NSSortDescriptor to sort NSDate objects in an ascending order. However, I need nil dates to be at the bottom of the list, whereas at the moment they come at the top.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the end I have decided that having nil values is not a good idea and if I want what were nil value to appear at the bottom of the ascending list I should set the dates to [NSDate distantFuture] and them check for this before displaying them. It turns out this makes more semantic sense in within the applications as well.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you already have a solution, but for anyone else looking to still use nil NSDates, and have them at the bottom, I use the following code where I sort descending, and then reverse the order of the objects sent to the compare.

```
_sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dueDate"
                                                ascending:NO
                                               comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)  {
                                                   return [obj2 compare:obj1];
                                               }];
```

Comment: does the compare not have undefined behaviour if obj1 is nil and obj2 is a date?

Comment: Note for anyone trying to use this in Core Data: comparators are not supported and will throw a runtime exception (maybe only if your Core Data is SQLite backed)

Answer (score 6):

Of course, I should use

```
initWithKey:ascending:selector:
```

and write my own comparison selector

Comment: Exactly. Do you custom logic to handle nil values and then call  [myNSDateInstance compare:secondDate]; if second date is non nil.

Comment: That won't help, since `compare:` will be sent to the NSDate instances; if `nil` ends up the receiver, the result will be `NSOrderedSame`, and if the receiver is not `nil` but the argument is, I don't think any specific result is guaranteed.

Comment: This does not work when fetching from Core Data, unfortunately.