# Controlling the way NSSortDescriptor sorts nil values in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Given the following `NSSortDescriptor` for strings with  Core Data:

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"series" ascending:true selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]
```

The results are correctly ordered alphabetically ascending. However in instances where `series` is `nil`, strings with `nil` values are placed at the top, with non-nil values being sorted thereafter, E.G:

```
[nil, nil, nil, A, B, C, D...]
```

Is there any way to control this behavior? Core Data does not allow for custom selectors. Here's a similar question to mine (not addressing Core Data's limitation, however):

[NSSortDescriptor and nil values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021213/nssortdescriptor-and-nil-values)

Comment: As far as I have dig. I think you can't. You'll have to create another with no nil values.

Answer (score 10):

While you cannot use a custom selector with Core Data, you can subclass `NSSortDescriptor` to change the default behavior. Something like this should work:

```
#define NULL_OBJECT(a) ((a) == nil || [(a) isEqual:[NSNull null]])

@interface NilsLastSortDescriptor : NSSortDescriptor {}
@end

@implementation NilsLastSortDescriptor

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone*)zone
{
    return [[[self class] alloc] initWithKey:[self key] 
                           ascending:[self ascending] selector:[self selector]];
}

- (id)reversedSortDescriptor
{
    return [[[self class] alloc] initWithKey:[self key] 
                           ascending:![self ascending] selector:[self selector]];
}

- (NSComparisonResult)compareObject:(id)object1 toObject:(id)object2 
{
    if (NULL_OBJECT([object1 valueForKeyPath:[self key]]) && 
        NULL_OBJECT([object2 valueForKeyPath:[self key]]))
        return NSOrderedSame;

    if (NULL_OBJECT([object1 valueForKeyPath:[self key]]))
        return NSOrderedDescending;

    if (NULL_OBJECT([object2 valueForKeyPath:[self key]]))
        return NSOrderedAscending;

    return [super compareObject:object1 toObject:object2];
}

@end
```

Comment: The `NULL_OBJECT` macro evaluates `a` twice. It doesn't change the semantics in this case because there's no side effects from the argument, but one could easily forget that in future. It does end up doubling the calls to `-valueForKeyPath:` and `-key`. Better to use a static inline function. While you're at it, might as well make those calls only once in `-compareObject:toObject:`. The nature of sort descriptors is that they are called frequently, so performance matters. Finally, `[NSNull null]` is documented to be a singleton, so you can just use pointer equality to check that.

Comment: This approach did not work for me when used in a fetched results controller. I suspect in this case CoreData converts the sort descriptors to SQL queries, never calling compareObject:

Answer (score 8):

Swift 4.1 version:

```
class NilsLastSortDescriptor: NSSortDescriptor {

    override func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        return NilsLastSortDescriptor(key: self.key, ascending: self.ascending, selector: self.selector)
    }

    override var reversedSortDescriptor: Any {
        return NilsLastSortDescriptor(key: self.key, ascending: !self.ascending, selector: self.selector)
    }

    override func compare(_ object1: Any, to object2: Any) -> ComparisonResult {


        if (object1 as AnyObject).value(forKey: self.key!) == nil && (object2 as AnyObject).value(forKey: self.key!) == nil {
            return .orderedSame
        }

        if (object1 as AnyObject).value(forKey: self.key!) == nil {
            return .orderedDescending
        }
        if (object2 as AnyObject).value(forKey: self.key!) == nil {
            return .orderedAscending
        }

        return super.compare(object1, to: object2)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Curious if we should be using `value(forKey:)` or `value(forKeyPath:)`

Comment: This seems to work, but as @joel.d mentioned, `NSFetchedResultsController` doesn't seem to care about it. Which is problematic :) Any ideas on how to make FRC work with it?

Comment: This also does not work when using `@FetchRequest` in SwiftUI