# Realm Swift: always put nil values last in sort

Tags: swift, realm

I'm writing an app in Swift 2.2 targeting iOS 8 and using Realm. I allow the user to sort objects based on various optional properties using `Results.sorted(_:ascending:)`. This works very well for descending sorts but for ascending sorts, `nil` values are placed first which doesn't look right. Many database systems have a `NULLS FIRST/LAST` option and with CoreData, it looks like it's possible to [subclass `NSSortDescriptor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701511/controlling-the-way-nssortdescriptor-sorts-nil-values-in-core-data). Is there any way to always put `nil` values last when sorting in Realm? Even if there's only a hacky strategy, that would be appreciated, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Realm doesn't support custom sorting of `Results` other than what the `Results.sorted(_:ascending:)` method gives you. But you can compose this yourself fairly easily by concatenating two queries, maybe even exposing that through a computed property:

```
var results: [MyModel] {
  let sorted = realm.objects(MyModel).sorted("...", ascending: true)
  return sorted.filter("optionalProperty != nil") +
         sorted.filter("optionalProperty == nil")
}
```

Comment: any way to do that without having to convert `Results` into an array?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, multiple queries would have been difficult because in most cases my data source already does that with other sorting priorities and I only need this custom nil sorting in one circumstance. It's also very possible for there to be hundreds or thousands of results, which I would rather not keep in memory by concatenating results.

So while this is not ideal, I chose to store a `hasStartDate: Bool` property which is updated automatically by a computed property `date: Date?` with a custom setter that updates the stored `startDate: Date?` and `hasStartDate` properties. `hasStartDate` is also set in my initializers for the object.

This allows me to use:

```
realm.objects(SMItem.self).filter(predicate).sorted(by: [
    SortDescriptor(keyPath: "hasStartDate", ascending: false),
    SortDescriptor(keyPath: "startDate", ascending: true)
])
```

This returns objects with a `startDate` ascending, followed by objects without a `startDate`.